# Listing all branches in a repo using Github API only returns the first 30

Tags: javascript, github-api, github.js

I'm using the [Github Javascript API](http://github-tools.github.io/github/) in my project. My repo has over 30 branches, so when I use the [listBranches()](http://github-tools.github.io/github/docs/3.2.3/Repository.html#listBranches) function I only get back the first 30 branches instead of all of them. I see in the response that there are more pages of branches...

```
link: '<https://api.github.com/repositories/000000000/branches?page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/repositories/000000000/branches?page=2>; rel="last"',
```

however I don't see any way to use this wrapper library to get the additional pages. Is there something I'm missing or am I going to have to hit the Github endpoints directly without this library?